# Why can't i cast (byte) Data Type into (short) Data Type in Java

Tags: java, types, casting, byte

So, Actually Im still new in Java Programming Language and still learning about casting Data type So in this case, i have a trouble in casting Byte into Short. Can You guys help me??

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(Strings[] args) {
        int number = 2;
        long updateNumber = number + 2;
        System.out.println(updateNumber); //output : 4
    }
}
```

So in this case, i can cast from (int) into (long) Data type normally because (long) data size is bigger than (int). it's the same case as when i trying to cast it from (short) into (int). But why can't i use this concept to casting Data Type from (byte) into (short)?? eventhough (short) has Data size bigger than (byte)??

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(Strings[] args) {
        byte number = 2;
        short updateNumber = number + 2;
        System.out.println(updateNumber); //output : Error
    }
}
```

I guess thats it.. Sorry for the trouble and Thank youu hehe..

Comment: Because the addition is performed with data type `int` (`2` is an int literal), and `int` is larger than `short`. Also to get terminology correct, there is no casting involved in these examples.

Comment: Ah i see.. i thought this is called Implicit casting.. and.... Ahh.. i get it. So is every math expression (+,- etc) will turn the data types into ` int ` if the size is smaller?? @Henry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we add two `byte` type variables or `byte` type variable with `int` type variable the result is automatically cast (**implicit casting**) to `int`. So the compiler will give error if we want to assign the result of addition to a short type variable.

While you can assign it to short type variable by **explicit casting**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException {
        byte number = 2;
        //Explicit casting
        short updateNumber = (short) (number + 2);

        System.out.println(updateNumber); // output : Error
}
```

As the result of the addition can overflow because here number variable value can be changed at runtime. So if you declare number as final and addition of the numbers fits in range of byte then you won't need to do explicit casting because compiler would be knowing in advance weather the result of addition can be hold by byte or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException {
        final byte number = 2;
        //Explicit casting not needed as number is final
        short updateNumber = number + 2;
    
        System.out.println(updateNumber); // output : Error
 }
```

Comment: Ah.. I see.. correct me if i'm wrong.  so, is (number+2) data Type here is actually integer type? but because you change into short type explicitly, it changes rightt??? is it the reason because (+ 2) is int type in the first place??

Comment: Yes, because now you are taking responsibility of this casting if the result value overflows. As well as if you declare the variable number as final and the result can be hold by byte then you won't even need to do explicit casting.

Comment: Ah i see... soo, as long it's still in range of some types, you don't need to explicit casting... Get it thank you